# confusion about PCA algorithm matlab

Tags: pca

I am given a data set with 500 features and I am told to apply PCA and find most important 2 features. I wrote some MATLAB code but I am very confused with all this PCA thing.

```
mean(projectData)
projectData = bsxfun(@minus,projectData,mean(projectData));

[coeff,score,latent] = pca(projectData);
```

This what I wrote but I do not know what to do next. I think I must print latent and take 2 values which are highest and assume their index to be feature number. This is what I understand. Please help me.

Comment: (first substract the mean from the data) then either compute `eig()` of correlation matrix of data or do `svd()` on data directly and get first 2 features (as both return the features sorted by variance, thus highest the variance the most important the feature)

Comment: @Nikos M. how do I know what feature is corresponding to what variance

Comment: The same ordering used for singular/eigen values (variances) same ordering is used in the feature vectors produced by both `eig` and `svd` so first (highest) variance corresponds to first unitary vector and so on